# Developping a Qt game engine under GPL-3 license: can I force users to pay a fee if they want to commercialize their games (software output)?

Tags: gpl-3, commercial

I'm using Qt Open source so I have my software under GPL-3 license. I would like the engine to be free for users that are not using their output games for commercial use. For commercial use, I would like to ask for some fees. I know that as long as a user pay fees for the software license it can be redistribute without charges and that's the wrong point. What about outputs?

What the output contains:

- Javascript interpreted source code under GPL-3 license
- Assets (does GPL license allows me to produce output containing commercial assets?)
- Dynamically linked Qt libraries
- Executable generated by Qt

I was thinking about asking users for autorization for using assets under that license: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/. However, I guess that Iloose all the rights to ask for fees if they remove the assets and use their own assets. Is there any possible trick to do my purpose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-commercial licensing recommendation](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6719/non-commercial-licensing-recommendation)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm not sure about having to put my JavaScript source code under GPL-3 license since it can work on any web browser without any change. Qt only makes it available on desktop application. Can I use a dual license to use CC-Non-Commercial for my creations (assets + JavaScript code)?

Comment: That seems to me to be a completely different question; it would be better to ask it as one.

Comment: See also: [Is the output of an open source program licensed the same?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/is-the-output-of-an-open-source-program-licensed-the-same)

Comment: Your question may actually be about non-GPL assets in a GPL program. See here: [Can a video game have a GPL licensed engine and GPL-incompatible licensed assets? What about scripts?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6253/can-a-video-game-have-a-gpl-licensed-engine-and-gpl-incompatible-licensed-assets)

Comment: What makes this interesting in my mind is the fact that you can get a non-free license for Qt for use in closed source/commercial work. But..  If I use your Qt-gpl based game to go non-free I'd need a non-free Qt license as well - depending on how your code is structured, it may not be GPL-able in that case.  Alternatively, you could hire lawyers and figure out how to duplicate Qt's dual license setup.

Comment: In fact, I didn't see that a large set of Qt libraries were also under LGPL-3 license. If I understand it well, this makes me able to have my output under another license even if it's using Qt libraries. I just have to use dynamic linking.